# New ecs deploys without downtime

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, ecs-taskdefinition

I have an ECS - EC2 configuration with a single task.

How can I launch a new version of the task so that there is no downtime, i.e. this version of the task is only replaced when the new version is 100% active? This way, I avoid as little downtime as possible.

This would solve two problems.

1. No downtime when uploading new versions of tasks.
2. I'm using SPOT and this would avoid changing instances before the service/task is available.

Comment: There are multiple deployment strategies that do not have downtime, but the one you describe is blue/green. There are many tutorials for implementing the strategy with ECS.

Comment: Take a look at the [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/create-blue-green.html) to create Amazon ECS service using the blue/green deployment, step 1 through 5